# MS Access - Summing up a field to be used in another query is "duplicating" data

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, join, aggregate-functions

I am trying to sum up one field and use it in another query, but when I use the **Totals** button and then call that sum from the other query it considers that field as multiple instances but with the sum value in each one. How can I sum two fields in two different queries and then use those sums in another query? Note - I only separated them into 3 queries because I felt it would help me avoid "is not part of an aggregate function" errors.

**Example Data**

Inventory Query: This query groups by item and sums the qty_on_hand field

```
Item     SumOfqty_on_hand
A           300
```

Job Material query: This query groups on the job's materials and sums up the qty_req field (quantity required to complete the job)

```
Item        SumOfqty_req
 A              500
```

When I make a third query to do the calculation [SumOfqty_req]-[SumOfqty_on_hand] the query does the calculation but for **each record in the Job Material query.**

**Job Material Query**

```
SELECT dbo_jobmatl.item, 
       IIf(([qty_released]-[qty_complete])<0,0,([qty_released]-[qty_complete]))*[matl_qty] AS qty_req
FROM new_BENInventory 
       INNER JOIN (dbo_jobmatl 
           INNER JOIN new_BENJobs 
              ON (new_BENJobs.suffix = dbo_jobmatl.suffix) 
                AND (dbo_jobmatl.job = new_BENJobs.job)
       ) ON new_BENInventory.item = dbo_jobmatl.item
GROUP BY dbo_jobmatl.item, 
         IIf(([qty_released]-[qty_complete])<0,0,([qty_released]-[qty_complete]))*[matl_qty];
```

**Inventory Query**

```
SELECT dbo_ISW_LPItem.item, 
       Sum(dbo_ISW_LPItem.qty_on_hand) AS SumOfqty_on_hand,
       dbo_ISW_LP.whse, 
       dbo_ISW_LPItem.hold_flag
FROM (dbo_ISW_LP INNER JOIN dbo_ISW_LPItem 
        ON dbo_ISW_LP.lp_num = dbo_ISW_LPItem.lp_num) 
     INNER JOIN dbo_ISW_LPLot 
        ON (dbo_ISW_LPItem.lp_num = dbo_ISW_LPLot.lp_num) 
          AND (dbo_ISW_LPItem.item = dbo_ISW_LPLot.item) 
          AND (dbo_ISW_LPItem.qty_on_hand = dbo_ISW_LPLot.qty_on_hand)
GROUP BY dbo_ISW_LPItem.item, 
         dbo_ISW_LP.whse, 
         dbo_ISW_LPItem.hold_flag
HAVING (((Sum(dbo_ISW_LPItem.qty_on_hand))>0) 
       AND ((dbo_ISW_LP.whse) Like "BEN") 
       AND ((dbo_ISW_LPItem.hold_flag) Like 0));
```

**Third Query**

```
SELECT new_BENJobItems.item, 
       [qty_req]-[SumOfqty_on_hand] AS [Transfer QTY]
FROM new_BENInventory 
       INNER JOIN new_BENJobItems 
          ON new_BENInventory.item = new_BENJobItems.item;
```

Please note that anything that starts with `dbo_` is a prefix for a table that sources the original data.

If any more clarification is needed I would be more than happy to provide it.

Comment: Your example queries don't have a column named 'Material'. Should that be 'Item' instead? And how many rows are you expecting to get in the result? Normally when you do an inner join, you get as many rows out as there were matching combinations in the input. Did you want to aggregate it further?

Comment: Well they are both called "Item" but I wanted to differentiate a bit. I'll fix it. I only want 1 row at the end of all this. The Inventory Query could have 10+ rows and the Job Material Query could have 15+ rows but I only want to take those rows, group on item, and then sum the quantities, resulting in 1 row from the Inventory Query and 1 row from the Job Material Query. Then I need to subtract these from each other.

Comment: Using every day language, the goal of this is to find out how much of a particular item I need across all open jobs that are using this, then subtract how much of this item we already have at the location to figure out exactly how much I need to transfer from another location (I can use a simple `IIf` to get rid of the negatives).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a `GROUP BY new_BENJobItems.item` on your final query along with a `SUM()` on the quantity. Or to remove the `IIf(([qty_released]-[qty_complete])<0,0,([qty_released]-[qty_complete]))*[matl_qty]` from your Job Material query. Or both. As written, the Job Material Query is going to return a record for every different key value in the joined input tables that has a distinct quantity, which doesn't seem like the granularity you want for that.

Comment: Using what you wrote above my query says "Running query" for a really long time...